# ¿Como imprimir el indice de los elementos de un arbol?

Tags: c++

Desde un árbol AVL me piden imprimir el indice que es un valor entre paréntesis de los nodos, los cuales están dados por ejemplo el nodo padre tiene el valor de x, que en este caso x vendría a ser 1; el hijo izquierdo tiene el valor de 2x, el hijo derecho tiene el valor de 2x+1 y así sucesivamente con los hijos de cada uno que depende de la cantidad de elementos que tenga el árbol . Adjunto un ejemplo y parte del código. Existe alguna manera de poder imprimir los indices, solicitando desde el main que se ingrese el nodo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <functional>
        using namespace std;

        template<class T>
        struct Node {
            T key;
            struct Node* left;
            struct Node* right;
            int height;
            Node() {
                left = right = nullptr;
                height = 0;
            }
        };

        template<class T>
        class ArbolAVL {
        private:
            Node<T>* raiz;
            void(*procesar)(T);
            typedef function<int(T, T)>comp;
            comp comparar;

            int max(int a, int b) {
                return (a > b ? a : b);
            }

            int _altura(Node<T>* nodo) {
                if (nodo == nullptr) return -1;
                return nodo->height;
            }

            bool _insertar(Node<T>*& nodo, T e) {
                if (nodo == nullptr) {
                    nodo = new Node<T>();
                    nodo->key = e;
                }
                else if (e < nodo->key) {
                    _insertar(nodo->left, e);
                }
                else if (e > nodo->key) {
                    _insertar(nodo->right, e);
                }

                //INI_DE_BALANCEO
                int hi = _altura(nodo->left);
                int hd = _altura(nodo->right);
                int d = hd - hi;
                if (d > 1) {//pesado a la derecha
                    int hni = _altura(nodo->right->left);
                    int hnd = _altura(nodo->right->right);
                    if (hni > hnd) { //zig zag derecha izquierda
                        _rotarDer(nodo->right->left, nodo->right, nodo->right);
                    }
                    _rotarIzq(nodo, nodo->right, nodo);
                }
                else if (d < -1) { //pesado a la izquierda
                    int hni = _altura(nodo->left->left);
                    int hnd = _altura(nodo->left->right);
                    if (hnd > hni) {//zig zag derecha izquierda
                        _rotarIzq(nodo->left, nodo->left->right, nodo->left);
                    }
                    _rotarDer(nodo->left, nodo, nodo);
                }
                //FIN_DE_BALANCEO

                hi = _altura(nodo->left);
                hd = _altura(nodo->right);
                nodo->height = 1 + ((hi > hd) ? hi : hd);
                return true;
            }

            //p is paren of x
            void _rotarDer(Node<T>*& x, Node<T>* y, Node<T>*& p) {
                p = x;
                y->left = x->right;
                p->right = y;
            }

            //p is paren of x
            void _rotarIzq(Node<T>* x, Node<T>*& y, Node<T>*& p) {
                p = y;
                x->right = y->left;
                p->left = x;
            }

            void _inOrder(Node<T>* nodo) {
                if (nodo == nullptr) return;
                _inOrder(nodo->left);
                procesar(nodo->key);
                _inOrder(nodo->right);
            }
            bool _buscar(Node<T>* nodo, T e) {
                if (nodo == nullptr) return false;
                int r = comparar(nodo->key, e);
                if (r == 0) return true;
                else if (r<0) { return _buscar(nodo->right, e); }
                else {
                    return _buscar(nodo->left, e);
                }
            }

            void _mostrar(Node<T>* nodo, int cont) {
                if (nodo == nullptr) return;
                else {
                    _mostrar(nodo->right, cont + 1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
                        cout << "   ";
                    }
                    cout << nodo->key << endl;
                    _mostrar(nodo->left, cont + 1);
                }
            }

            void _indice(Node<T>* nodo, T e) {
                int cont=1;
                if (nodo == nullptr) return;
                else {
                    int r = comparar(nodo->key, e);
                    if (r == 0) { cout<<cont; }
                    else if (r < 0) { 
                        cout<<cont*2+1;
                        /*return _indice(nodo->right, e);*/ 
                    }
                    else if(r>0) {  
                    cout<<cont* 2;
                    /*return _indice(nodo->left, e); */
                    }

                }
            }

        public:
            ArbolAVL(void(*pf)(T)) {
                this->procesar = pf;
                this->comparar = [](T a, T b)->int {return a - b; };
                raiz = nullptr;
            }
            int cont = 0;

            void insertar(T e) {
                _insertar(raiz, e);
            }

            void mostrar() { _mostrar(raiz, cont); }
            void inOrder() {
                _inOrder(raiz);
            }
            bool buscar(T e) { return _buscar(raiz, e); }
            void indice(T e) {  _indice(raiz,e); }
        };
```

#

```
#include "arbol.h"

using namespace std;

void imprimir(int e) {
    cout << " " << e;
}
                  int main()
        {

            ArbolAVL<int>* tree = new ArbolAVL<int>(imprimir);

            int opcion;
            int elemento;
            int valor;
            int num;
            do
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << ".:MENU DE OPCIONES:." << endl;
                cout << "1. Insertar un nuevo elemento al arbol: " << endl;
                cout << "2. Buscar un elemento del arbol: " << endl;
                cout << "3. Mostrar: " << endl;
                cout << "4. Saber indice de un elemento: " << endl;
                cout << "5. Salir: " << endl;
                cout << "  ¿ Que opcion desea ? ";
                cin >> opcion;
                switch (opcion)
                {
                case 1: {
                    cout << "Ingrese un elemento al arbol: ";
                    cin >> elemento;
                    tree->insertar(elemento); } break;
                case 2: {
                    cout << "Ingrese el elemento a buscar: ";
                    cin >> valor;
                    if (tree->buscar(valor) == true) { cout << "El elemento " << valor << " si se encuentra en el arbol" << endl; }
                    else { cout << "El elemento no se encuentra en el arbol" << endl; }
                    system("pause");
                }break;
                case 3: {tree->mostrar(); cout << endl;
                    system("pause"); }break;
                    case 4:
                    cout << "Ingrese el numero del que quiere saber el indice: ";
                    cin >> num;
                    tree->indice(num);
                    cout << endl;
                    system("pause");
                    break;
                }
            } while (opcion != 5);

            cin.get();
            cin.ignore();
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿ Cual es el problema concreto que te has encontrado ? ¿ Error del compilador ? ¿ Resultados esperados no coinciden con los obtenidos ? ¿ Que esperas ? ¿ Que obtienes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te explicare como podrías hacerlo, básicamente te explicare cual es la lógica que deberías de seguir para logar tu objetivo, ya que no puedo ayudarte con codigo porque rompería las reglas de es.stackoverflow. Ademas de que creo que tienes mucho código para realizar cosas simples.

Utilizaremos el siguiente arbol:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- realiza una función que recorra un nivel especifico del arbol: mostrarNivel(raiz,nivel,indice).

```
 Ej: mostrarNivel(raiz,0,1)//resultado 2(1)
 Ej: mostrarNivel(raiz,1,1)//resultado 7(2)  5(3)
 Ej: mostrarNivel(raiz,2,1)//resultado 2(4)  6(5)  9(6)
```

El indice depende mucho de como lo estes tratando en tu arbol.

2.- Realiza una funcion para obtener la altura de tu arbol.(esta no te la explico porque al parecer ya la tienes). Aclaramos que: `nivel=altura-1` ó `altura=nivel+1`

3.- Entonces lo que faltaría es tan simple como hacer un for:

```
para nivel=0 hasta (altura-1) hacer
    imprimir mostrarNivel(tu_raiz,nivel,1)
```

Esa seria la logica para realizar lo que pides.